# Heroku C application. Server using TCP/UDP sockets

Tags: c, sockets, heroku

I am working on a server application using BSD Sockets, its a C project and has been built on Heroku, using a custom buildpack.

I cant figure out how to execute the binary afterwards?

The buildpack contains:

```
bin/
    detect.sh
    compile.sh
    release.sh
```

release.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# bin/release <build-dir>
cat <<EOF
---
config_vars:
PATH: /app/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
EOF
```

The binary builds fine using `make` as reported in the activity feed of the dashboard.

I need to run the server so I can connect to it using the client I have developed from my local machine.

EDIT: I have added a Procfile and to run the binary the procfile contents are:

```
spinup: bin/serverUDP 1071
```

`serverUDP` is the name of the binary file inside the bin/ folder of the application.

EDIT:

Build log:

```
-----> Fetching set buildpack https://github.com/damorton/heroku-buildpack-c.git... done
-----> C app detected
-----> Compiling with Make
make: `vendor/bin/busltee' is up to date.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> spinup
-----> Compressing... done, 4K
-----> Launching... done, v20
       https://hangman-udp.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Logs:

```
 2015-12-04T10:45:25.977074+00:00 heroku[spinup.1]: Process exited with status 0
2015-12-04T10:45:25.992332+00:00 heroku[spinup.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2015-12-04T10:51:53.697297+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy ebe93d8 by damorton@xmail.com
2015-12-04T10:51:53.697370+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v21 created by damorton@xmail.com
2015-12-04T10:51:55.209687+00:00 heroku[spinup.1]: Starting process with command `bin/serverUDP 1071`
2015-12-04T10:51:55.814271+00:00 heroku[spinup.1]: State changed from starting to up
2015-12-04T10:51:57.750368+00:00 heroku[spinup.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Command after deploy:

```
heroku ps:scale spinup=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the `Procfile` is used to execute the binary after the build. The problem I was having then wasnt related to the binary being executed, it was that the binary wasnt being built. So I used a `cmake` build pack to install cmake. Then I used cmake to build my project. All worked out fine on the build side except for linking to a relative directory for the shared libs.

For anyone with the same problem:

- Use buildpacks for `cmake` and then `c`
- Use `Procfile` to execute binary with arguments after build

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it built and deployed successfully a single dyno should load the slug and execute the command. To scale and/or change the dyno configuration, you'll need to issue a command with your chosen option. For example:

```
 $ heroku ps:scale web=2 queue=1
```

This would start three dynos; two for web and a single one for queue processes. You can also scale the individual power of the dynos by increasing the RAM and CPU share using a similar command:

```
 $heroku ps:scale web=2:standard-2x  queue=1
```

Comment: My problem is that I can't tell if a dyno has loaded the binary or if its running.

Comment: Running `heroku ps` tells me that the process has crashed.

Comment: Do you have any logs or dumps that give any details about the process crashing?